# How to know if object address is 0x0?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to check if my object address is 0x0. How to do it in objective c?

Comment: What's wrong with `myPointer == 0` (assuming something like `id myPointer = ...` or `NSString* myPointer = ...`). Or even `!myPointer` or `myPointer == nil`? Am I missing something?

Comment: I have already tried it. It does not work. I have UIView. When I wath address it shows 0x0. But comparing with nil does not work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just compare the reference as

```
if (obj == nil)
```

or

```
if (obj == NULL)
```

or

```
if (obj == 0)
```

or

```
if (!obj)
```

You can use any one of them they all are same.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(object == nil){

// it means memory for this object is not allocated 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test for a nil pointer like this:

```
if (!myObject) {
    // myObject is nil (0x0).
}
```

Or like this:

```
if (myObject == nil) {
    // myObject is nil (0x0).
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already tried it. It does not work. I have UIView. When I wath address it shows 0x0. But comparing with nil does not work...

Comment: if(view == 0)
        {
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        }
        else if(view == NULL)
        {
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
        else if(view == nil)
        {
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }

Comment: Put an NSLog in all your if blocks.

Comment: Then most probably it will go into the `if (view == nil)` block and not do anything because you can't set the backgroundColor of nil, obviously. Put an NSLog after each `setBackgroundColor`.

Comment: I am sorry. I just restarted my xCode. Now it works. Yes, you were right if(view == nil) is ok. Thank you very much!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

that address is equals to nil so you nust need to compare it with `nil`